# I do not need dot and dotdot

Tags: c++, qt

when I list entries via QDir::entryInfoList I'm getting two extra entries, one with dot and second one with two dots. If I set QDir::NoDot and QDir::NoDotDot then nothing is listed. I need just the contents of the folder I'm passing to QDir, nothing else.

```
 QFileInfo fi(model_->filePath(e));
        auto file_path = fi.absoluteFilePath();
        auto lyst = QDir(fi.absoluteFilePath()).entryInfoList(/*QDir::NoDotAndDotDot makes lyst empty*/);
        foreach (QFileInfo info , lyst)
        {
            qDebug() << info.absoluteFilePath();
        }
```

Comment: Well the `.` and `..` entries are also part of the folder.

Comment: Show us the line where you are setting NoDot and NoDotDot.

Comment: @KristerAndersson yes, but I don't need them

Comment: @Rob When I do set it then lyst is empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` [filter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdir.html#Filter-enum) ORed with `QDir::Files` or anything of your interest to `entryInfoList`

```
auto lyst =
 QDir(fi.absoluteFilePath()).entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot|QDir::AllEntries);
```

Comment: if I do that nothing is listed in my lyst variable.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/22178-QDir-NoDotAndDotDot-hidding-all-files):

> The default value for the filter flags is `QDir::AllEntries`. When you override the default flags with `QDir::setFlags` or `QDir::entryList`, you should not forget to include at least one of `QDir::Dirs`, `QDir::Files`, or `QDir::Drives` to get any entries.

I imagine your code would look like this (haven't tested it):

```
QFileInfo fi(model_->filePath(e));
auto file_path = fi.absoluteFilePath();
auto lyst = QDir(fi.absoluteFilePath()).entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files);
foreach (QFileInfo info , lyst)
{
    qDebug() << info.absoluteFilePath();
}
```